# Loading XML Internally in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.IO;

```
public class xmlhandler{
public XmlNodeList GetData(string xmlfilepath,string tag)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); // xmlDoc is the new xml document.
    TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(xmlfilepath, typeof(TextAsset));
    xmlDoc.Load(textAsset.text); // load the file.
    XmlNodeList data = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(tag); // array of the level nodes.
    return data;
}
}
```

`

I can not seem to be able to get the xml to load properly. It is the correct path when called and everything, I checked. I'm not sure what other information to give. I assume I'm just not using the right function or something. Sorry for the lack of knowing what is going on.

The error I'm getting is

```
ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:508)
System.IO.Path.InsecureGetFullPath (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:357)
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:289)
System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri)
System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url, System.String& absoluteUriString)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url, System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt)
System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url, System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt)
System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename)
xmlhandler.GetData (System.String xmlfilepath, System.String tag) (at Assets/Resources/scripts/xmlhandler.cs:13)
structure_mercenarypost.Start () (at Assets/Resources/scripts/structures/structure_mercenarypost.cs:24)
```

Comment: What is the Xmlfilepath that you are giving. Because your error is saying, it contains illegal characters.

Comment: info = xml.GetData("scripts/structures/structuresxml", "structure");

Comment: If `info` is what you are passing as a path. Then I can understand that it is failing. You need the file path.

Comment: But resources.load loads it from the local assets of the game..

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument.Load()` accepts a file *path*. What you're passing into it is the entire content of your XML (which is likely full of angle brackets, causing this particular error).

Instead of `Load()`, you want to use `LoadXml()`. That method accepts the XML string you're pulling out of your `TextAsset`.